# Reordering a .bib file

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

This is probably a really stupid question but I can not seem to find an answer for it.  I am currently reordering a .bib file to put it in alphabetical order.  This is ok but when I compile my original document doing latex-bibtex-latex-latex nothing changes in the references section even though I made changes to the references.bib file.  I am confused as to why this does not change anything.  Do I need to typeset the bibliography in some way? I have saved it and it is in the right folder so I do not know what is going on.

Here is what I have as an example because reading my question again I realized it was unclear.

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\normalem
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{bm}

% Bibliography
\usepackage{cite,amssymb}
\usepackage[labeled,resetlabels]{multibib}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{L}{Links}

\usepackage{url,graphicx,tabularx,array,geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}

\title{blah}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
 text and math with some citations like this \cite{chapman2000high}, \cite{robinson2013wing}, \cite{wardn}. 
\nocite{*}
\nociteL{*}


newpage

\bibliographystyleL{ieeetran}
\bibliographyL{Links}{}


\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}
\bibliography{References}{}
\end{document}
```

And here is what some of my bibliography looks like

```
%%%%%
@book{chapman2000high,
  title={High speed flow},
  author={Chapman, C. J.},
  volume={23},
  year={2000},
  publisher={Cambridge University Press}
}

%%%%%%
@book{robinson2013wing,
  title={Wing theory},
  author={Robinson, A. and Laurmann, J. A.},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Cambridge University Press}
}
```

I guess I just do not understand the ieeetran part.  This is not originally my work I was just asked to edit it.

Comment: the bib file is a database of references the order of entries in the file makes no difference. the role of bibtex is to extract some subset of the entries and sort into a specified order depending on the bibtex style, usually order of reference in the document, or alphabetic list of authors.

Comment: if my guess is correct, the `\bibliographystyle` you are using is causing the items to be rearranged in your bibliography.  the style `unsrt` will arrange them in the order in which they are referred to in the text.  the other possibility is that you have not rerun bibtex since reorganizing the `.bib` file.  (these are both, of course, just wild guesses, as you haven't provided any concrete evidence to go on.)  in the `unsrt` case, you might be able to hijack that by putting `\nocite{*}` in the file before your first reference.  (this too is a guess.)

Comment: I have edited the question to include code.  I have typeset latex then bibtex  then latex twice @barbara beeton and it did nothing

Comment: try the `alpha` style instead of `ieeetran`, and as @DavidCarlisle said, the order in the *.bib file does not affect the order of the bibliography, that's the whole point of having a bib file in the first place...

Comment: `\nocite{*}` causes the whole `.bib` file to appear in your document which is normally _not_ what you want, other than for testing purposes, typically you may be using a bib file of thousands of potentially useful references and bibtex will extract the ones that are used in this particular document and sort them in to whichever order the bibliography style specifies.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you see any reasonable action here?

Comment: @Johannes_B not sure if it's reasonable but I'll make my comment an answer, to clear this off the list

Answer (score 1):

The bib file is a database of references. The order of entries in the file makes no difference.

The role of bibtex is to extract some subset of the entries and sort into a specified order depending on the bibtex style, usually order of reference in the document, or alphabetic list of authors.